# Handler to serve pages differently to mobile and computer browsers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, mobile

In our company we create landing pages using HTML and javascript. I want to create a handler that detects the whether the user is entering the site with a mobile device or a computer and display the different landing pages accordingly. I don't need a complete explanation on how to do this but I would very much like a basic outline as to what I should be doing and what I should research to do this

Thanks.

E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deliver a response according to the browser type by using the following steps:

1. [Detect Browser Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx)
2. Send the appropriate view

As an alternative you can [detect the browser type using JavaScript](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jbrowse.htm) and modify the page on the client side, or use [CSS @media types](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet).

Comment: The problem is the landing pages are static HTML pages without any server side.

Comment: Then you can use JavaScript-based browser detection and/or CSS